# Magento 2- How I can change my blocks and theme to RTL when change To Arabic Store?

Tags: magento2

I have Magento theme with a two-store views `English` and `Arabic` the default theme is working great for the `English` view but for the `Arabic` view I want to change all the layout to be `RTL`.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change direction to RTL for Arabic Store, then you have to add **direction:rtl** in your style.css for Arabic store.

Comment: where i can find it in my arabic store?

Comment: if you have a common css, then you have to add direction based on  **"lang: ar"** . You can see this **lang:ar** in html tag. By using this **lang:ar**, you can add  **direction:rtl** in CSS by taking as a parent class.